# cannot display fetched api data in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

am trying to display the first name of a user from a fetched api data... What could be wrong with this Reactjs code?
i confirmed there was data already fetched from the api, but in displaying it... it returns blank and no errors

```
class App extends Component 
    constructor() {
      super()
      this.state = {
        loading: false,
        user: {}
      }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({loading: true})
      fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users/2")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          user: data
        })
      })
    }
  render() {
    const text = this.state.loading ? "loading..." : this.state.user.first_name
    return (
      <div>first name: {text}</div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

Comment: what does `data` look like in `.then(data => {`

Comment: You can make this a bit less redundant if you make this to `this.state = {loading: true}` and then removing `this.setState({loading: true})` in `componentDidMount`

Comment: {"data":{"id":2,"email":"janet.weaver@reqres.in","first_name":"Janet","last_name":"Weaver","avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg"},"ad":{"company":"StatusCode Weekly","url":"http://statuscode.org/","text":"A weekly newsletter focusing on software development, infrastructure, the server, performance, and the stack end of things."}}

Comment: Try this way this.setState({
          loading: false,
          user: data.data
        })

Comment: Try `this.state.user.data.first_name`

Comment: [This](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html) should help! In your example, data is not really the data but the result. My guess is that you can access the data in the result using `data.items` or `data.data`.  (One of these should work)

Answer (score 1):

You name the whole response `data` in the final `then` callback function.
The response itself also contains another Object called `data`, to access that you should use `data.data` in your `setState` .

You might like to de-structure it like this in your callback:

```
fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users/2")
.then(response => response.json())
      .then({data} => {
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          user: data
        })
})
```